# MongoDB Java driver - date query

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, mongodate

I am new to MongoDB and Java and I am trying to retrieve data from MongoDB using a date field.

Data:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "timeSlice" : [ 
            2018, 
            5, 
            1
        ],
        "type" : "TRANSMISSION",
        "@objectName" : "SettlementInstance"
    },
    "Versions" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "dc57888a-c070-465f-9f2d-cbc5f2b69a09",
            "status" : "ACTIVE",
            "version" : NumberLong(10007)
        }
    ]
}
```

MongoDB query I use:

```
db.getCollection('SettlementInstance').find({"_id.timeSlice" : [2018,5,1]})
```

How to use this date field in Java with SQUARE Brackets and Integer dates together?

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: your query looks OK to me. Try this `db.SettlementInstance.find( { "_id.timeSlice": { $all: [ 2018,5, 1 ] } } )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will find the document you supplied in your question:

```
// 3.x driver idiom
Bson filter = Filters.eq("_id.timeSlice", Arrays.asList(2018, 5, 1));

// 2.x driver idiom
// Bson filter = new BasicDBObject("_id.timeSlice", Arrays.asList(2018, 5, 1));

collection.find(filter);
```